# Python - Circular import with super function calling method

Tags: python, class, import, circular-dependency, super

I have two files. The code seems like having circular import between each other. How can I solve it? I have to use super function to call the function in first file.

report.py

```
import report_y as rpt
from aldjango.report import BaseReport

class Report(BaseReport):
    def gen_x(self):
        output = rpt.Ydetail(*args)
        ....
        #code that generate a PDF report for category X

class HighDetail(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ....   
     #functions that generate output
```

report_y.py

```
from report import HighDetail
class YDetail(HighDetail):
    #do something override some argument in HighDetail method
    new_args = orginal args + new args
    super(YDetail, self).__init__(*new_args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It looks like the first file, `report.py` is importing _itself_ -- which I think is the actual problem.

Comment: sorry, it's a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a more concise, minimal example to reproduce your problem:

a.py

```python
import b

class A(object):

  def get_magic_number_from_b(self):
      return b.magic_number()
```

b.py

```python
import a

def magic_number():
  return 42

class B(a.A):
  pass
```

Similar to your example, class B in module b inherits from class A in module a. At the same time, class A needs some functionality from module b to perform its function (in general, you should try to avoid this if you can). Now, when you import module a, Python will import module b as well. This fails with an `AttributeError` exception since the class b.B depends explicitly on a.A, which is not yet defined at the time when the `import b` statement is executed.

To solve this issue, you can either move the `import b` statement behind the definition of A, like this:

```
class A(object):

  def get_magic_number_from_b(self):
    return b.magic_number()

import b
```

, or you move it to within the definition of the function that depends on the functionality from module b, like this:

```
class A(object):

  def get_magic_number_from_b(self):
    import b
    return b.magic_number()
```

Alternatively, you can make sure that you always import module `b` before module `a`, which will also solve the problem (since a has no import-time dependencies on b).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "circular import" problem in Python.  Importing a module that has already been imported is quietly ignored.  Any initialization code will only be run on the first import of the module.

This is true even when a module is given an alias with import...as.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to resolve the issue would be to move the class `HighDetail` into `report_y.py`